# Looking for User Management setting enableCanAnswerContainUsername in Salesforce UI

Tags: metadata, configuration, help

I am currently trying to deploy the UserManagment.setting metadata but running into some issues due to environment versions. I have decided to manually configure it but cannot seem to locate where to configure enableCanAnswerContainUsername in the UI.

Within the metadata, I can change the value for enableCanAnswerContainUsername to false, but where do I find this in the UI?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an undocumented feature. It has no UI, doesn't appear in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_usermanagementsettings.htm), Trailhead Communities, or any Release Notes, and has just five hits on Google, including a single GitHub repository and this Q&A. If you need to change this setting, you'll need to use the Metadata API. Given that this setting isn't documented anywhere, I'd advise changing it from `true` in any org, because you might be setting a trap for you, or a future administrator, when or if this feature becomes documented/publicly available.

Comment: Thank you so much for this information